# How does Chrome share data between its processes?

Tags: google-chrome

I also would like to apply the same technique to my app, but I don't know how Chrome shares data(of the current tab) to the main process(user interface). How would that be possible? How they do it?

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? What data would you like to share? Please describe some scenario you are trying to implement.

Comment: Similary to chrome there are tabs on the main ui. But not for browsing, but each for creating an instance of one game. To make it more stable, I think it will be better if I apply Chrome's scenario and every game instance has its process. Better than having much threads. The main thread would 'read' data from its child processes somehow and display it in the user interface. Only data that is to be shown on the interface.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this design document](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication), Chrome uses [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) as its IPC transport mechanism on Windows platforms, and [socket pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) under Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways processes can communicate with each other:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Apache webserver uses a [Scoreboard file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#scoreboardfile) to coordinate between the master and slave processes.

It initially tries to use a shared memory segment (such as from `shm_open(2)`), followed by `mmap(2)` of a plain file. Either approach works well. I imagine Apache forces all accesses to its scoreboard via semaphores (`sem_open(2)`), but if the updates are atomic single-writes, it may not need to.